# Unable to dissociate chat room

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When creating a new chat room, it's possible to not associate it with a specific site, if you choose "The Stack Exchange Network" from the site list (it appears twice for some reason, but that's a separate issue):

[image: Screenshot of the site list]

However, when editing a room, the option doesn't appear on the host list:

[image: Screenshot of the host list]

Neither does `(default)`, the host unassociated rooms typically have. As far as I can tell, there's no way to dissociate an existing room from a site; it has to be created with no site and left that way

Comment: Will investigate. Is there a specific room here? we can edit it directly ;p

Comment: @Marc No, I just happened to notice it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK; all addressed:

- the duplicate now isn't duplicated duplicated
- the network-wide option is now available (when appropriate - i.e. chat.SE)